# How can I add a combobox in control designer properties for a WinForms custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom control with a property that can take value from a set of strings like "Man, Woman". So in in control designer properties I want to show a combobox with these 2 choices.

Is there a standard way to do so ? If not what should I implement ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The simple way to do that is to add an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) to your code that defines the possible choices for your property, then configure your custom control's property to accept a value of that type.** The Properties Window will automatically display a combo box for this property with all of the possible values in your enum listed.

So, for example:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Man,
    Woman,
}

public class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public Gender UserGender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you do it, without a enum?  I want to be able to get a list of all the controls on a form or if I have a control get all the child controls in it and let you the user select one of them from a dropdown menu in a property grid.

Comment: @tobeypeters Did you ever found out how to do it ? I am facing the same requirement

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, you should create an enum like:

```
enum Person
{
    Man,
    Woman
}
```

and then make your property of type Person. It should appear in properties as a drop down list.